# How to make vscode start with a blank file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use vscode instead of notepad. I prefer to type as fast as possible when launching vscode but i can't seem to find this option to do this. Does anyone know what this option is named after or if it's possible with a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Torge Rosendahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10875738/torge-rosendahl) whose [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74213913/how-to-make-vscode-start-with-a-blank-file/74220079#comment131029094_74213913) provided the answer:

> The setting you are looking for is `workbench.startupEditor`

Answer (score 4):

This can by making a small tweak in vscode settings. All you need to do is open preferences and search for **Startup editor**. Under the *Workbench* section you'll find the **Workbench: Startup Editor** option. Change the value of this option to *newUntitledFile*.

[image]